# how to pass variable between 2 classes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have class to define import to news table of database from xlsx file.
**App\Imports\NewsImport.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Imports;

use App\News;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class NewsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        News::truncate();
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        { 
            News::create([
               'title'      => $row['title'], 
               'fulltext'   => $row['fulltext'], 
            ]);
        }
      return $newsimported = $rows->count();
    }
}
```

then import is managed in SeedController
**App\Admin\Controllers\SeedController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Encore\Admin\Controllers\Dashboard;
use Encore\Admin\Layout\Column;
use Encore\Admin\Layout\Content;
use Encore\Admin\Layout\Row;
use App\Imports\NewsImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class SeedController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Content $content)
    {
        Excel::import(new NewsImport,       'import/news.xlsm');
        return $content
            ->title('Import & Export')
            ->description('Laravel excel');
    }

}
```

I launch import when I go to seed page

```
$router->get('seed', 'SeedController@index')->name('admin.home');
```

Code is working, but I want to show on seed page how many news have been imported.
But I don't know how to make **$newsimported** available in SeedController index function.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking into the implementation details of the Excel library you could try adding a member variable to that Import class you have created and then checking that after `Excel::import(...)` has ran:

```
class NewsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
    public $rowCount = null;

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        News::truncate();
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        { 
            News::create([
               'title'      => $row['title'], 
               'fulltext'   => $row['fulltext'], 
            ]);
        }

        $this->rowCount = $rows->count();
    }
}
```

Then where you are running `Excel::import(...)`:

```
public function index(Content $content)
{
    Excel::import($import = new NewsImport, 'import/news.xlsm');

    $rowCount = $import->rowCount;

    ...    
}
```